# the &nbsp; is not working in IE10

Tags: html, internet-explorer-10

Hello guys i wanna have spaces between my option values in my code only first option value is working in IE10 but no the second and third also in other browsers it work f9.

Any one please help me

here is the code:

```
        <div class="propertystatus">  <!-- start of propertystatus -->   

                   <label id="rent"  style=" cursor:pointer;">
     &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; // THIS IS WORKING IN IE10

<input type="radio" name="radio"  value="For Rent" id="rent" />
                   <font size="+1">کرایی</label><br />

     &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; // these not working in IE10
    <label for="lease"  style=" cursor:pointer;"> <input type="radio" name="radio" id="lease" value="For Lease" />
                        گرویی</label><br />

    &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; // these not working in IE10
     <label for="sale"  style=" cursor:pointer;"><input type="radio" name="radio" id="sale" value="For Sale" />
                        فروشی</font></label>
```

Comment: don't use `<font>` tag. It was deprecated in 1998!!! Use CSS

Comment: “Not working” is not a problem description. What is the expected rendering, and how does the observed rendering differ from it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put a ´margin-left´ (or ´margin-right´) in the label's or input's style where you need space.

BTW you should put all your styles in an external CSS file.